# Lock or protect a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Are there one or more ways to lock or protect a `data.table` such that it can no longer be modified in-place?

Say we have a data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1, val="foo")
dt
#    id val
# 1:  1 foo
```

Can I then modify `dt` to get the following behavior after?

```
dt[, val:="bar"]
# error or warning
dt
#    id val
# 1:  1 foo  ## unmodified
```

### Context

This came up because I author a small R package at work that uses `data.table` extensively. It has some `data.tables` in it (translation tables) which, if accidentally modified by a user, would cause issues (improper translations). I had hoped that making the data "internal" (as defined [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)) would solve this but it does not.

Because this is only an issue with `data.table` objects, I could just use data.frames, copying + casting to `data.table` as needed within functions. I will go this route if needed (my tables are small enough that the time/memory overhead won't be noticed), but I'm hopeful there's a more natural solution.

Comment: Can you explain more fully why using internal data doesn't solve your problem? A determined user will always be able to break anything you do.

Comment: @joran internal data can be accessed like `packageName:::dt`, and thus can be modified in-place like `packageName:::dt[, val:="bar"]`. Unlikely, I know, but it made me curious about the possibility of locking `data.tables` in general.

Comment: @ClaytonJY perhaps `:=` could respect `lockBinding` - might be worth adding a feature request

Comment: You can try my [data.table "read.only" branch](https://github.com/jangorecki/data.table/tree/read.only). See [compare](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/compare/master...jangorecki:read.only). You just set an attribute `setattr(x,"read.only",TRUE)` and the first `[` makes a copy. Could be improved to make shallow copy.

Comment: @eddi/Jan: I like both of those ideas, though they both require changes to the package itself. I filed a generalized feature request listing both proposals here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1086

Comment: @eddi Good proposal! I have tried it and discovered that `lockBinding` does not prevent `:=` from changing the `data.table` object (using data.table_1.10.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible ideas.

You could write your own wrapper object (possibly use the R6 package) that defines all the editing tools to give the error and not change the underlying data.table, but uses the standard data.table access functionality for just reading the object.

You could follow the approach of the `petals` function in the TeachingDemos package.

Both of the above are not perfect and a determined person could still change them.  They are probably also not worth the work needed.

You could reread your tables each time your function runs, so that changes would need to be made on the disk, not just in R.

There are tools/packages to compute things like the MD5sums, so you could calculate that for your data.table, then when the code runs you could check the MD5sum and stop if it has changed.

You can have the data.tables saved in a .Rdata style file and attach the file onto the search path rather than load it into the working directory.  It could still be changed, but less likely to happen by chance and would require more effort to change (make sure that your code does not access local copies in the global environment (use `get` or `::` or check that a local copy does not exist)).

Comment: What is the approach of your `petals` function?

Comment: @ClaytonJY, the key piece of code has been "Bleached", i.e. it has been encoded as a series of spaces and tabs which are then converted on the fly to the actual code used.  This makes it difficult for a novice to cheat by looking at the code (but an intermediate level R programmer could easily figure out what the code is, but it would be clear cheating and could not be claimed to have been seen by accident).

Comment: Ah okay, that's an interesting approach! Thanks for the range of options you've provided here.